# What's the difference between "crumpled cube" and "3-ball"?

Tags: geometric-topology

Warning: My level of understanding of topology is very low. Small words would be appreciated. :)

Browsing Wikipedia, I came to [crumpled cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crumpled_cube), defined as "a 2-sphere together with its interior". Intuitively, I would think that "the interior of a 2-sphere" is exactly synonymous to "an (open) 3-ball", and "together with" means "union", and therefore the whole definition is synonymous with "a closed 3-ball". But if that were true, then we would have no need for the term *crumpled cube*.

What's the difference between "3-ball" and "crumpled cube"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odd as it may sound, not every subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$ that is homeomorphic to a 2-sphere is the boundary of something homeomorphic to a 3-ball. One famous example of this is the [Alexander horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere). In the terms of that article, the solid Alexander horned sphere (the exterior of the Alexander horned sphere, together with the point at infinity) is a particular crumpled cube that is not a 3-ball.

Comment: I'm willing to believe that, but I could use more details, like, is it true that every(thing homeomorphic to a) 2-sphere is the boundary of *something*? is this the same thing as having an "interior"? and how do we show that a particular 2-sphere's interior isn't (homeomorphic to) a 3-ball?

Also, that Wikipedia article [currently claims *"The horned sphere, together with its inside, is a topological 3-ball…"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Alexander_horned_sphere&oldid=571752668), which seems like the opposite of what you just said!

Comment: Every topological 2-sphere in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is the boundary of something. This is the 3-dimensional [Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem#Proof_and_generalizations). But we don't get very much information about *what* it's the boundary of (unlike in 2 dimensions, where the [Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem) tells us that nothing weird can happen). The proofs of all of these theorems are absurdly hard.

Comment: The solid Alexander horned sphere is actually the *exterior* of the horned sphere, as usually presented. (As contrasted with the Alexander horned ball, which is the interior, and which is a ball.)

Comment: aha, I see. So the Wikipedia article was correct, but it would also be correct to add that *"The horned sphere, together with its **outside**, is **not** a topological 3-ball…"*. Both "sides" are crumpled cubes, but only one of them is a 3-ball. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right (at least, as long as you're thinking about the horned sphere as a subset of $S^3$, so the exterior is actually compact).